# Plot a point on a surface

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot a point (in a shape of a small sphere) lying on the surface $z=10-x^{2}-y^{2}$. But it seems that the spherical point is being distorted. How can I make it round?

This is my code:

```
Show[Plot3D[10 - x^2 - y^2, {x, 0, 3.3}, {y, 0, 3.3}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], PlotRange -> {-1, 12}, 
  AxesStyle -> Thick, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], Graphics3D[{Blue, Sphere[{1, 2, 5}, 0.2]}],
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Use `BoxRatios -> Automatic` instead of `{1,1,1}`.

Comment: @Artes Thanks so much. It works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep `BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}`, you can do

```
plt1 = Plot3D[10 - x^2 - y^2, {x, 0, 3.3}, {y, 0, 3.3}, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], PlotRange -> {-1, 12}, 
   AxesStyle -> Thick, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}];

pr = PlotRange[plt1];

br = {1, 1, 1};

scale = Norm[Subtract @@ Transpose[pr]] Normalize[-Subtract @@@ pr]/br;

Show[plt1, Graphics3D[{Blue, Scale[Sphere[{1, 2, 5}, .1], scale]}], 
 BoxRatios -> br]
```

[image]

With `br = {1, 1, 3}` we get

[image]

and with `br = {1, 3, 2}` we get

[image]

**Update:** ***"... add an arrow (normal vector) to the point"***:

```
plt1 = Show[
   Plot3D[10 - x^2 - y^2, {x, 0, 3.3}, {y, 0, 3.3}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], Mesh -> None, 
    PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], PlotRange -> {-1, 12}, 
    AxesStyle -> Thick, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], 
   Graphics3D[{Red, Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[.04], 
     Arrow[{{1, 2, 5}, {3, 6, 6}}]}], PlotRange -> All];
pr = PlotRange[plt1];
br = {1, 1, 1};
scale = Norm[Subtract @@ Transpose[pr]] Normalize[-Subtract @@@ pr]/br;

Show[plt1, Graphics3D[{Blue, Scale[Sphere[{1, 2, 5}, .1], scale]}], 
 BoxRatios -> br]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. This is what I am looking for. Keeping the prescribed ratio has some avantages.

Comment: From a mathematical point of view your solution makes a confusion since a small sphere is always simply a sphere, while the graph of the function is being rescaled, even though one can believe it is a good `Mathematica` approach.

Comment: @Artes I understand that it is not a good Math point of view, but in my opinion, it's useful as a good way to present Math to general audiences, who may only accept that a small point on a surface should appear like a small sphere.

Comment: @Artes, excellent point. The different scalings for  the surface and the  _small_ sphere actually means the two are on different coordinate systems and the axes of the latter not explicitly drawn.

Comment: @kglr Hi, could you manage the same thing if I add an arrow (normal vector) to the point: 
Graphics3D[{Red, Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[.04], 
  Arrow[{{1, 2, 5}, {3, 6, 6}}]}]

Comment: @Binjiu, pls see the update.

Comment: @kglr Thanks, but it seems that the vector {3,6,6} is not orthogonal to the tangent plane 2*x + 4*y + z - 15 =0 at the point {1,2,5}.